# Recovery options for running-config Cisco ASA (running IOS 8.2)

Tags: cisco-asa

We're setting up an ipsec tunnel and as I look at the config to apply, I'm not really comfortable with how to rollback our changes.

I'm familiar with saving the config in this manner:

`copy running-config startup-config`

I'm familiar with loading config in the opposite way:

`copy startup-config running-config`

However I understand that last command will do more a merge of the previous config than overwriting, and isn't a guarantee of restored values.

The only sure-fire method I know of would be to run a `reload`, which would wipe the running-config and load entirely from startup-config on the reboot, but that would then make interruption of network traffic certain, perhaps taking some minutes.

Is there another way to recover the config more dependably?

I found a command called [configure replace](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/config-mgmt/configuration/xe-3s/config-mgmt-xe-3s-book/cm-config-rollback.html), which looks promising, but it doesn't look as if I have it on my ASA:

```
ciscoasa(config)# configure ?

configure mode commands/options:
  WORD             Configure from HTTP:
                   http(s)://[<user>:<password>@]<location>[:<port>]/<pathname>.
                   Place IPv6 address within square brackets if a port is
                   specified. 
  factory-default  Configure from factory-default
  memory           Configure from memory
  net              Configure from tftp

exec mode commands/options:
  terminal  Configure using terminal/console
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed `copy startup-config running-config` will do a merge, not an overwrite.
So you can do the following:

> clear config all
>
> copy startup-config running-config

Obviously this will still cause a brief outage as there is a (very short) timeframe during which the ASA operates with the default config, but it should definitely be shorter than rebooting.

Just make sure to do this on the console, if you do it over SSH you could cut yourself off.

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was looking for.  Though it always startles me a little to see how short and powerful these commands are. :)

Answer (score 1):

On ASA **no** **nothing** very **friendly**,

```
copy flash:backup-config startup-config 
reload
```

I always keep copies of configurations offsite and typically track the commands I ran to revert if needed.

1) do not write config unless your confident it's correct.

2) send configs offsite often.

3) if you can, configure archive

```
config t
archive
path flash:archive-config (**Note: you can save to a tftp server using “path tftp://10.0.0.1/”)
log config
logging enable
logging size 500
hidekeys (**Note: prevents logging of passwords)
notify syslog (**Note: produces a syslog message and should be used if you are capturing syslogs from your devices)
maximum 6 (**Note: Maximum number of backups)
write-memory (**Note: captures an archive each time you write to nvram)
```

[archive example source](http://www.configurationdepot.com/everything/cisco-archive-command-and-configuration/)

cattools are also nice.

Lastly, if you cannot at anytime reload any router for any reason, you clearly do not have the proper redundancy configured.  I would highly recommend if the business model cannot support a few minutes of downtime to reload the config in case of an issue during maintenance hours, it can afford a redundant unit.

Comment: I certainly agree a business critical environment should have a redundant setup, but this would not help with this problem; rebooting one ASA would just cause it to re-sync the 'bad' config from the other one.

Comment: I never said how they would be configured.

Comment: Are you aware of an active-passive configuration that wouldn't pass the bad config before reloading?  Or are you suggesting the mirrored relationship be broken before proceeding?

Comment: I'd use routing and run them independantly, but I'd also be running eigrp/bgp

Comment: This is a close example, but not exactly how I'd set things up.  http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/news/2240034709/Cisco-ASA-firewall-advice-Using-ASA-84-for-stateful-failover-in-DRP